# как из функции досстать сумму массива

Tags: c++

рекурсивный подход, чтобы сгенерировать все возможные комбинации размера n из заданного массива

```
void generate_combinations(const std::vector<int>& ls, std::vector<int>& combination, int start, int k) {

    if (k == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < combination.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << combination[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= ls.size() - k; i++) {
        combination.push_back(ls[i]);
        generate_combinations(ls, combination, i + 1, k - 1);
        combination.pop_back();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> ls = {91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87};
    int k = 3;

    std::vector<int> combination;
    generate_combinations(ls, combination, 0, k);

    return 0;
}
```

в вектор combination записываются и выводятся все возможные варианты без повторений
т.е вывод будет

```
50 55 56 
50 55 57 
50 55 58 
50 56 57 
50 56 58 
50 57 58 
55 56 57 
55 56 58 
55 57 58 
56 57 58
```

как сложить все числа этого вектора чтобы получить их сумму

```
50 55 56 -> 161
50 55 57 -> 162
50 55 58 -> 163
50 56 57 -> 163
50 56 58 -> 164
50 57 58 -> 165
55 56 57 -> 168
55 56 58 -> 169
55 57 58 -> 170
56 57 58 -> 171
```

Comment: Простите, непонятно, что надо получить в конечном итоге? Все комбинации, сумму по каждой комбинации или общую сумму для всех комбинаций?

Comment: в конечном итоге нужно было получить сумму вектора combination.
combination на первом шаге = 50 55 56.  И нужно было получить его сумму 161.

но я уже разобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void generate_combinations(const std::vector<int>& ls, std::vector<int>& combination, int start, int k) {
    
        if (k == 0) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < combination.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << combination[i] << " ";
                sum += combination[i];
            }
            std::cout << "-> " << sum;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = start; i <= ls.size() - k; i++) {
            combination.push_back(ls[i]);
            generate_combinations(ls, combination, i + 1, k - 1);
            combination.pop_back();
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
        std::vector<int> ls = {91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87};
        int k = 3;
    
        std::vector<int> combination;
        generate_combinations(ls, combination, 0, k);
    
        return 0;
    }
```